# Pandas DataFrame color highlight based off values closest to observed

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to stylize text in a `panada DataFrame` that compares values from two columns to a third, ie I want to see which of the values for `case1` and `case2` are closest to the `obs` (observed) value and highlight the closest value in green and the other in red.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([["PSL",1001,1004,1002],
                   ["LWCF",23.5,25,22.2]
                  ], 
                  columns=["VAR",'case1','case2',"obs"])
```

I have been successful when using a helper function for an individual row that finds the closest value and sets the colors appropriately:

```py
def color_rule(val,i):
    case1 = df["case1"].values[i]
    case2 = df["case2"].values[i]
    obs = df["obs"].values[i]
    return ['background-color: green' if x == min([case1,case2], key=lambda x:abs(x-obs)) else 'background-color: red' for x in val]
```

```py
df.style.apply(color_rule, axis=1, subset=['case1','case2'],i=0)
```

[image]

```py
df.style.apply(color_rule, axis=1, subset=['case1','case2'],i=1)
```

[image]

However, if I try and run this for all rows, I have problems with truth elements:

```py
def color_rule(val):
    # try for all values of columns...
    case1 = df["case1"].values
    case2 = df["case2"].values
    obs = df["obs"].values
    return ['background-color: green' if x == min([case1,case2], key=lambda x:abs(x-obs)) else 'background-color: red' for x in val]

df.style.apply(color_rule, axis=1, subset=['case1','case2'])

>>> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I'm kinda stuck on how I could make this work for all rows of my data frame. I've tried putting a for loop inside the function, but it only grabs the colors for the last entry.

I'm guessing I will have to find a better solution for comparison than the line:

```py
min([case1,case2], key=lambda x:abs(x-obs))
```

One that would be a more `pandas-esque` way by doing it column-wide and not row by row, but I'm not super familiar with pandas on this level.

Comment: What's your goal? `df.style.apply(func, axis=1)` will call `func` for each row, so the style is being applied to each row. Are you trying to avoid doing it row-by-row and instead do it for the whole table in one go?

Comment: @richardec, yeah I'm trying to have the whole table done at once so every row has values of ```case1``` and ```case2``` that are either green or red. The ultimate goal is to have this finished table exported to a csv file

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Your to screenshots show that all rows of `case1` and `case2` are colored...?

Comment: For each row, I would like one case to be red and one case to be green. In each of my screenshots, only one row ends up having one green and one red, while the other row is all red. The desired outcome would be in row 1: ```case1``` is green and ```case2``` is red and in row 2: ```case1``` is green and ```case2``` is red. Hope this clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea but I think the `color_rule` needs to be quite a bit smarter. It is applied row by row (with `axis=1`) which is the right direction as you have relationships that define colors within each row separately. so the `val` passed to the function is a row of a dataframe, which is a Series.

Also I assume you do not want to color `obs` column itself, which adds a bit of a complication

Here is my version. I also took the liberty of making it slightly more robust so it can handle dfs with multiple columns. It colors the closest and the furthest away and keeps the rest uncoloured

```
def color_rule(row):
    # Name of the column to which we compare
    obs_col_name = 'obs'

    # names of all other columns that we compare to 'obs', without 'obs'
    case_cols = [col for col in row.index if col != obs_col_name]

    # here we will keep colour rules
    cr = []

    ## loop over all column names
    for colname in row.index:

        # do not colour 'obs' column
        if colname == 'obs':
            cr.append('')

        # colour the closest green
        elif row[colname] == min(row[case_cols], key=lambda x:abs(x-row[obs_col_name])):
            cr.append('background-color: green')

        # colour the furthest red
        elif row[colname] == max(row[case_cols], key=lambda x:abs(x-row[obs_col_name])):
            cr.append('background-color: red')

        # Nether here nor there, do not colour
        else:
            cr.append('')
    return cr


df.style.apply(color_rule, axis=1, subset=['case1','case2','obs'])
```

output (as picture so you can see colors):

[image]

Let's apply it to a slightly more interesting case with another column:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["PSL",1001,1004,1002,1002.1],
                   ["LWCF",23.5,25,22.2,40]
                  ], 
                  columns=["VAR",'case1','case2',"obs","case3"])
df2.style.apply(color_rule, axis=1, subset=[c for c in df2.columns if c != 'VAR'])
```

output:

[image]

### (Perhaps) more Panda-esque solution

We can find Panda elements that are closest/furthest away from 'obs' without looping. Here is another solution that is more concise but perhaps not as expressive

```
# Only look at numerical columns
dfn = df2.select_dtypes(include=['int64','float64'])

# Find the closest and the furthest elements
obs_col_name = 'obs'
case_cols = [col for col in dfn.columns if col != obs_col_name]
dfa = (dfn[case_cols] - dfn[[obs_col_name]].values).abs()
min_mask = (dfa == dfa.min(axis=1).values.reshape(-1,1))
max_mask = (dfa == dfa.max(axis=1).values.reshape(-1,1))

# Put together a df with colors for the original df
df_color = df2.copy()
df_color.loc[:,:] = ''
df_color = (df_color.mask(min_mask, other = 'background-color: green')
                    .mask(max_mask, other = 'background-color: red')
)
df_color['obs'] = ''
df_color['VAR'] = ''
```

'df_color' now looks like this:

```
    VAR    case1                    case2                  obs    case3
--  -----  -----------------------  ---------------------  -----  -----------------------
 0                                  background-color: red         background-color: green
 1         background-color: green                                background-color: red
```

Then we can apply it to the original df:

```
df2.style.apply(lambda _ : df_color, axis=None)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks for your thorough explanation and examples. I totally overlooked I used min to find the closest, but max was there to do the opposite. Much appreciated!